# how do i do that string filter with filter list in python

Tags: python, string, list, filter

I want to filter a string from `iniFile` and turn it into a dict called `iniConf`:

```
iniFile ='''

conf = test.ini

\# conf = test2.ini
conf_type = single

\#conf_type = multi
'''

infilter = ['conf', 'conf_type'] # to use
exfilter = ['#', 'multi'] # to skip
```

After filtering, I want to get

```
iniConf = {'conf':'test.ini', 'conf_type':'single'}
```

Comment: You have neglected to ask a question. Please add one, ensuring that it isn't just "how do I do that".

Comment: sorry, it was depend on my poor english..T.T

Comment: Please edit the question, providing the code you have written so far and precisely what is wrong with it. Errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide inputs and expected and actual outputs)?

Answer (score 1):

The most robust way to parse ini files in python is to use the ConfigParser module, since then you don't have to deal with all the corner cases or parsing by hand.

Comment: Except that the OP's sample input is not valid INI since it has no section.

Comment: Thanks, but file name is just xxx.ini not exactly.